# AppGyver - phonegap remove loading transition screen

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

Hello I'm creating a simple mobile app using Appgyver - steroids. 
I'm new with this framework I'm trying to find a way to hide the loading screen between different pages in both Android and iOS. I have read their documentation but I can't make it work.
Based on this: http://docs.appgyver.com/en/edge/steroids_Steroids%20Native%20UI_steroids.layers_layers.push.md.html#steroids.layers.push

I 've set `keepLoading: false` on a view push which didnt work

also after the view push I called:

```
steroids.view.removeLoading();
```

as mentioned here: http://docs.appgyver.com/en/edge/steroids_Steroids%20Native%20UI_steroids.view_view.removeLoading.md.html#steroids.view.removeLoading

Nothing removed the black loading transition screen between pages.
Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It could be documented better, but if you remove/rename the `www/loading.html` (for iOS) and `www/loading.png` (for Android) files in your project, then `steroids.layers.push()` will not show the loading screen (also means that the push animation will not start until after the WebView has loaded, which can take some time and lead to unresponsive feeling).

Comment: I renamed loading.html and it does remove the loading but renaming the loading.png didn't have any effect. Any help why this happens ?

Comment: I wonder if push animation will not start until after the WebView has loaded? I removed my loading.html and it looks like the push animation starts quite fast, but the pushed view is still being rendered and some flickering happens inside the view.